# Dumping global variables in Robot Framework when a test fails?

Tags: robotframework

I have a doubtful pleasure to work with legacy tests written in Robot Framework that abuse usage of global variables.

I would like all global variables to be dumped when the test fails.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/robotframework-users/3RYrsz_cIY8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the built-in keyword [Log Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20Variables) in a [suite teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown) or [test teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown).

Here's an example that uses a suite teardown:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Teardown   log variables

*** Test cases ***
Test case 1
    set global variable  ${FOO}  Hello
    set global variable  ${BAR}  World
    Fail
```